# CSS Selector on onclick function

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to get a CSS selector on a `onclick` + `function()`? You can get it on the [`onclick`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24365416/select-element-which-have-specific-attribute).

Here is the HTML:

```
<span onclick="gotoURL(&quot;https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ&quot;);">Rick Roll</span>
```

CSS:

```
span[onclick] {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

But these don't work:

```
span[onclick="gotoURL"]

span[onclick="gotoURL()"]
```

Comment: try this `span[onclick*="gotoURL"]`

Comment: I'm gonne test this for a bit, but on first glance it works like a charm.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

sure there is a way ;)

> The [attribute^=value] selector matches every element whose attribute
>   value begins with a specified value.

```
span[onclick^=gotoURL]
```

Means grab span with attribute onclick which's value is starting with gotoURL.

https://jsfiddle.net/h0qg6nys/

Cheerio :)

**edit:** vivekkupadhyay was faster...

**edit 2:** btw. you can check this for selector references https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

**edit 3:** [*30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize*](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)

Comment: Yeah, but they couldn't be bothered to explain it, let alone post a full-fledged answer. So you get the vote.

Comment: Wasn't actually thinking he needs that *selector* solution, btw nice explaination :)

Comment: you trying to Rick Roll stackoverflow

Answer (score 5):

Just clarifying what is happening with the attribute selector.

- `span[onclick]` selects a span which *has* an `onclick` attribute, regardless of its value.
- `span[onclick="…"]` selects a span whose `onclick` value *exactly* matches something. That was your error: it didn’t match exactly
- `span[onclick^="…"]` selects a span whose `onclick` value *begins* with something. That is closer to what you were looking for.

The double quotes around the something aren’t always required, but you do need them if the something contains awkward characters such as slashes. It’s always safe to include them.

Modern CSS also includes `$=` which *ends* with a value, and `*=` which *contains* a value. This is not available in Legacy Browsers (ie IE).

CSS is not sophisticated enough (yet) to include more interesting pattern matches, so although you can look for `gotoURL` (`span[onclick]^=gotoURL`), there is no way to match `gotoURL()`.

Just as a side point, you really shouldn’t be using the `onclick` property anyway. It’s only there for people who haven’t heard of unobtrusive JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you add styling for focus maybe? 
It may work then. Or for an active as well.

```
span:focus,
span:active{
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```